# Split flat array into chunks of n elements, then reverse the order within each chunk

Tags: php, arrays, chunks, array-reverse

I want to reverse an array by two elements in each step. If I have an array [11,12,13,14,15,16], I want to reverse first two elements [11,12] and then another two elements [13,14] etc. The final array should be [12,11,14,13,16,15]; My code is below:

```
function reverseArray($array, $size){
    $reversed_array = array();

    $chunk = array_chunk($array, $size);
    $chunk_length = count($chunk);  
    for($i = 0; $i < $chunk_length; $i++){
        $reversed_array[$i] = array_reverse( ($chunk[$i]) );            
    }

    return $reversed_array;
}

$array = array(12,13,14,15);
$size = 2;
print_r(reverseArray($array,$size));


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 14
        )

)
```

How can I merge those two arrays into one? I tried to use array_merge but don't know how to use it in my function. Any idea?

Comment: `$reversed_array = array_merge($reversed_array, array_reverse( ($chunk[$i]) ));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function reverseArray($array, $size){
    $reversed_array = array();

    $chunk = array_chunk($array, $size);
    $chunk_length = count($chunk);  
    for($i = 0; $i < $chunk_length; $i++){
        $reversed_array = array_merge($reversed_array,array_reverse( ($chunk[$i]) ));            
    }

    return $reversed_array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `call_user_func_array` along with`array_reverse` and `array_chunk` to achieve your goal like as

```
$arr = [11,12,13,14,15,16];
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge',array_reverse(array_chunk(array_reverse($arr), 2)));
print_r($result);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/392363)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$input = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $input);
```

to flatten the array

---

But, your code can be simplified as below,

```
function reverseArray($array, $size)
{
    return call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map('array_reverse', array_chunk($array, $size)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common trick is utilizing [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) via [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array).

```
$array = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $chunks);
```

Which will call `array_merge` with whatever list of `$chunks[0], $chunks[1], $chunks[…]` as parameters.

You could simplify your arrayReverse function with [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) likewise, btw:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, $size);
$chunks = array_map("array_reverse", $chunks);
```